# How to add maven dependencies in Pom.xml file in IntelliJ manually

Tags: intellij-idea

I already created a springboot application and I am using IntelliJ as an IDE. I have missed out some dependencies while creating springboot application like Eureka Discovery client. I want to add that dependencies but when I add manually, it's not working in IntelliJ. Is there any way to add missed out dependencies in IntelliJ.

Thank you

[POM file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nuHH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I just need to add maven dependency option in the error that I got and it's solved. Thank you